# Connecting to Mongo using SQL - function syntax

Tags: sql, apache, mongodb, apache-drill, simba

I am trying to configure Microstrategy to work with MongoDB. The Mstr advised way is to use Simba ODBC driver. The simple connection works fine. The problems start when I want to use functions e.g. get only hour out of the timestamp.

The other approach I tried is to use Apache drill and I face exactly the same problem.

```
Select code, name from offer
```

Code and name are attributes of some documents in collection called offer. This works fine.

```
Select date(interactionDateTime) from interactionrecord
```

This fails. I tried different syntax postgres - date_part, to_date - Oracle, another one from MySQL..., EXTRACT etc.

Comment: Could you please provide more information? What version of Drill are you trying? What version of MongoDB? Microstrategy recently certified Drill for use with their tool.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the scalar functions listed here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms714639(v=vs.85).aspx

To extract the hour out of a time, use the HOUR() scalar function.